# MySQL how to create timestamp from year (argument), weekOfYear (argument), time (database) and dayofweek (database)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I need to implement showing of some events on an existing project. I can not change database structure.

In my controller I get passed (from ajax request) a timestamp and I need to show previous 8 events. So if timestamp is (converted) 2017-12-12 00:00:00 I need to show 8 events before 2017-12-12, ordered by their time DESC.

This is how my table is set up:

```
-calendarrepeat
 -dayofweek // int 1-7; 1 = monday, 7 = sunday
 -event_date_begin // date "2016-05-01" - indicates from which day the event recurrs every week (dayofweek)
 -event_date_end // date "2017-05-02" - indicates until which day the event recurrs every week (dayofweek)
 -event_hour_begin // time "11:00:00"
 -event_hour_end // time "12:00:00"
```

I can do whatever I want with the timestamp. I use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) so it's not a problem to get week of the year, day of the year or whatever else I would need.

For reference `$fullTs` is the timestamp I get passed into the controller. The join part works fine.

The part I need help with is: `/* THIS PART has to be rewritten (it's COMPLETELY wrong at the moment) ! */`

I need to generate timestmap from year (passed as argument), weekOfYear (passed as argument), day of week (from database column) and time (database column). I would need something like this instead (pseudoSQL):

`->where(\DB::raw('THISTHINGY_TO_DATE($fullTs->year $fullTs->weekOfYear calendarrepeat.dayofweek calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin, "%Y %week-of-year %day-of-week %H:%i:%s), '<', $fullTs)))`

This is the full query I'm currently running (the first part of UNION, the second one works as intended):

```
$eventsRepeat = CalendarRepeat::join('calendarrepeat_translations', function ($j) use ($locale) {
        $j->on('calendarrepeat.id', '=', 'calendarrepeat_translations.calendarrepeat_id')
            ->where('calendarrepeat_translations.locale', '=', $locale);
    })
    ->orderBy('calendarrepeat.event_date_begin', $orderBy)
    /* THIS PART has to be rewritten (it's COMPLETELY wrong at the moment) ! */
    /* the STR_TO_DATE(..) part has to get date from a) week passed in $fullTs b) dayoftheweek written in calendarrepeat.dayoftheweek c) time written in calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin */
    ->where(\DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(calendarrepeat.event_date_begin, ' ', calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"), '<', $fullTs)
    ->where('event_date_begin', '>', $fullTs)
    ->where('event_date_end', '<', $fullTs)
    ->limit(8)
    ->select([
        'calendarrepeat.event_date_begin as date', 'calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin as start',
        'calendarrepeat.event_hour_end as end', 'calendarrepeat_translations.title as title', \DB::raw("CONCAT(calendarrepeat.event_date_begin, ' ', calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin) as date_whole") // This is also wrong
    ]);
```

Is that possible? How? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Another thing to be careful about is that in our DB 1 = monday, 7 = sunday, which from my understanding isn't a common way to enumerate week days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check the result you have got:

```
$eventsRepeat = CalendarRepeat::join('calendarrepeat_translations', function ($j) use ($locale) {
$j->on('calendarrepeat.id', '=', 'calendarrepeat_translations.calendarrepeat_id')
    ->where('calendarrepeat_translations.locale', '=', $locale);
})->select([
  'calendarrepeat.id',
  'calendarrepeat_translations.calendarrepeat_id',
  'calendarrepeat_translations.locale','calendarrepeat.event_date_begin as date',
  'calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin as start',
  'calendarrepeat.event_hour_end as end',
  'calendarrepeat_translations.title as title',
  \DB::raw("CONCAT(calendarrepeat.event_date_begin, ' ', calendarrepeat.event_hour_begin) as date_whole")
])->where(\DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', start), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"), '<', $fullTs)
->where('date', '>', $fullTs)
->where('end', '<', $fullTs)
->orderBy('date', $orderBy)
->limit(8);
```